# jquery reading elements of inner div with id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have following div structure

```
<div id="6" >
   <div><h4>Heading</h4></div>
   <div idd="2">
     <h5>3883</h5>
   </div>
</div>
```

In my code I am trying to read id and idd

```
   onDrop(element.attr('id'), element.attr('idd'));
```

It reads the value of id fine for idd it says undefined.
Please let me know how to change the last part to read idd value too. Thanks

Comment: check my answer please

Comment: its better to give a little more details on the problem at hand to be able to give more and precise answer

Comment: `element` refers to which `div`? Be specific for both the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this one that will get tag by attribute name

```
alert($("[idd]").attr('idd'))
```

Comment: Sorry it was typo I corrected. In code I have correct and I get undefined for idd value

Comment: @J. Davidson check my answer please

Answer (score 0):

Replace "idd" with "id" and you will get whatever you want.